# GTX 770 on Focal: HDMI choppy audio with nvidia driver -470

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

My new graphic card is a GTX770, on ubuntu 20.04.

I use DVI-D-0 output (for main thing) and HDMI-0 for games and films on TV (and randr script to switch from one to other).

With the 'nouveau' driver, sound with HDMI is ok, no problem. But only GL4.3 and slow graphic performance.
So I used system tool to instal the ubuntu-nvidia-470 driver, and all well.

Excepted the choppy audio through HDMI. The sound play for 0.5s, then silence for 5s, etc..
Problem only on hdmi, with nvidia driver.
Pulseaudio mixer recognise the hdmi port and can use it when it's plugged.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug in the nvidia driver's like this one:[no audio hdmi nvidia](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/no-audio-over-hdmi-with-nvidia-gt1030-and-benq-3270u-monitor-on-ubuntu-18-04/73616).

I was using 640x480 and that was the problem. All other resolutions works fine with audio via hdmi.
I just have to wait for bug correction and use another resolution.